# xcode quiz app: how do not repeat one quest. from plist file

Tags: xcode

i have quiz app for the iPhone, i'm able to load random question from plist file and i want to ask about 20 questions; in my plist file i have 20 more, but i don't want that in one quiz session one question is repeated. 
this is my plist file `

```
<key>Domanda1</key>

    <dict>

    <key>immagine</key>

    <string>hpv</string>

    <key>Titolo</key>

    <string>Domanda numero 1</string>

    <key>Risposta1</key>

    <string>Risposta primaD1</string>

    <key>Risposta2</key>

    <string>Risposta seconda</string>

    <key>Risposta3</key>

    <string>Risposta terza</string>

    <key>Risposta4</key>

    <string>Risposta quarta</string>

    <key>Soluzione</key>

    <integer>1</integer>

</dict>

<key>Domanda2</key>
```

.......
`
my view controller.m

```
-(void)creaDomanda {

//scelta casuale tra le varie disponibili

int randomValue =  (arc4random() % 20) + 1;

NSString *stringa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Domanda%i", randomValue];

// Apre il dictionary

dictionary = [plistData objectForKey:stringa]; 

// e stampa a schermo la domanda

label1.text = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Titolo"];

label1.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

.........

Any ideas? 
thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a mutable array and copy your questions into it in numerical order.  Select questions from the array using a random value.  When you ask a question, remove it from the array.  To generate a new random value, use the number of items still in the array instead of "20".

Comment: thank you for your solution, tonight i will try...since now i'm working hard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.But I did for 20 random numbers.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
BOOL isflag = NO;
int numberofquestions = 20;

for(int m =0; m<numberofquestions; m++)
{

    int question_number = (arc4random()%numberofquestions)+1;
    isflag = YES;

    for(int n = 0;n < (int)[array count];n++)
    {
        if([[array objectAtIndex:n] intValue] == question_number)
        {
            isflag = NO;
            m--;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(isflag == YES)
    {
        [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", question_number]];
    }
}
```

This array will give you the 20 random numbers without repeation.